# Cache not expired, but files will still download and overwrite

Tags: php, firefox, caching, google-chrome

The cache expiry date is one month. It is sent with the headers, but the files are still downloaded and overwrited every time I reload the page.

I am using Mozilla Firefox CacheViewer to view the cache.

However, in Google Chrome they are not overwrited. Only the Last Accessed time is updated. I am using ChromeCacheView to view the files.

Could anyone help me a little bit?

Comment: Are you using webdevelopper toolbar on FF? Is "unable cache" activated?

Comment: Yes I am. No, the cache is not disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I click on the address bar and type in my website address in firefox, then Firebug displays 38.3 KB (36.4 KB from cache).

When I press F5 in firefox, then Firebug displays 241.1 KB (10.9 KB from cache)

This means that Firefox controls the way the cache is being used by the browser.